# Updating Algolia record has a delay before you can query it

Tags: javascript, graphql, algolia

So I am using graphql (JS) for my algolia processes and I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/algoliasearch) framework.

I am doing:

```
await index.partialUpdateObject({someProp: newValue});`
```

Now, **EVERYTHING** works fine, however I noticed that if I (the user) performs an action search:

```
await index.search(query, options);
```

There's like a 1- 3 seconds delay before the data on my search gets updated.

---

Question: Is there a way to know when the data in algolia has finished updating? a push notification or something?

Comment: there is some `taskId` thing but I havent used it before

Comment: I see, I've looked into it and it seems that you still need to call another API to know the status, I couldn't find if this thing have a webhook or something tho

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/wait-task/#examples did you check this